# How to get jenkins to build my code even if there are no changes

Tags: jenkins

I am using the Jenkins matrix plugin for testing my project. I have an upstream, kick-off build that is fired of every night at a fixed time. This build performs a checkout and part one of the tests. It then passes the subversion url (SVN_URL) and revision (SVN_REVISION) to a downstream build. The downstream build then uses the passed in subversion url and revision to checkout the source (this way, I know that both the upstream and downstream builds are targeting the same revision), and performs part two of the tests.

The problem I have is that the downstream job sometimes doesn't run anything saying that there were no changes in the checked out source since the last build (no change for  since the previous build). I would like to get the downstream build to build every single time it is invoked, even if there are no changes. Any pointers on how to do that?

Thanks

(Edited in reponse to question)
Detailed jobs description:
1. Kickoff job. Run periodically. Captures SVN_URL and SVN_REVISION. Fires of part1-job and part2-job. Does not do anything else.
2. part1-job and part2-job are matrix jobs that do not have any triggers on them. They are merely run by the kickoff job.

part2-job is where I have the problem. Curiosly, the problem mentioned above does not happen for part1-job.

Comment: What do you have set in Build Triggers?

Comment: Here are the jobs: 1. kickoff (trigger: build periodically). Fires of part1-job and part2-job. 2. part1-job and part2-job have NO triggers. part2-job is the matrix job where I'm having this problem. It gets the SVN_URL & SVN_REVISION from the kickoff job.

Comment: Deleting the question. Turns out there was a bug in our internal scripts that would modify the test filter to eliminate the matrix elements. User error. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that storing the build output from the initial build and running the downstream job based on that artifact to be a solution to this problem.  I'm making some assumptions here about what you're doing in the initial and subsequent jobs, but our experience might be helpful.

For some tests where we perform a longer test after an initial build & test are successful, we now use the Artifact system to store the build results from the first build and then retrieve those at the beginning of the next test for execution. This works particularly well for lengthy build processes where you may need more than one test to run in parallel.

For example, our system looked something like this:

1. Build task
2. GUI Test on OS X 10.6
3. GUI Test on OS X 10.7
4. GUI Test on OS X 10.8

Initially, we ran these serially (all in one big build task), but then we changed our testing systems so that we could run the GUI tests in parallel and needed an efficient way to take the build output from a specific job and run it on each of the test environments in parallel.

Our new system runs like this:

1. Build task with Post Build action to `Archive Artifacts`
2. 3 different tasks that each run the GUI tests in one environment, each of which begins by  copying the artifacts from the first build stage (using `Upstream Build that triggered this Job`) and then using those artifacts as the execution targets for the test.

Now our tests run in parallel and are guaranteed to use the identical build.   This has the added bonus that the each build is only run once.

As an added bonus, we reduced the 3 tasks doing the GUI test to a single matrix task, but that's probably not relevant for your purposes (however, it's sure saved a lot of work for us).

Comment: thanks for responding. I do use artifacts from the upstream job. Unfornately, I also need the downstream job to perform a checkout, which is where the problem starts -- jenkins seems to perform the checkout and then not run the tests themselves since there were no changes.

Comment: Can you answer the question about how your triggers are currently set up?